# Best way of maintaining versions

Tags: versioning

I want to maintain version control in following application so what will be best option for maintaining version?

In my app there is tool which will generate resources as input for my frame work. 
For the sake of simplicity we can take a eg like in tool there are same options so one can set some values over there.
Just assume there are ten integer ctrl box are on tool and user can set values there so tool will generate the values either as xml file or some struct define in c as follows.
Note here parameters name like TITLE and DIALOG use respectively with Integer ctrl. these string name are ie TITLE/DIALOG will remain fixed.

```
<root>
<TITLE value = '1' />
<DIALOG value = '2' />
.
.
</root>
```

and

```
Struct data
{
1, //TITLE
2. //DIALOG
.
.
.
}
etc
```

So tomorrow it may possible there are some new parameter like TITLE and DIALOG may also added.
Then what is the best way to keep the version control in this scenario.

actually i am not talking about version control like perforce or svn, my question is regarding like if there are 10 parameters ot wd mine version 1.0 or if there are 12 param then it wd may 1.1 etc, like in that sense i am talking. I always want assurance that with these strings i will generate some key and this key will be write into the xml, then in framework i will calculate that key by those param so there is always assurance that data generated by tool is as same version with the current frame work version.

I know its bit lengthy but i hope it make problem more translucent
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a little more specific ?
If you talking about the versionning of your code, there existe an array of software that you could use. SourceSafe, Team Foundation, SubVersion and CVS are but a few. Some of them are pretty simple and free, while other are quite expensive but can be easily integrated into you IDE if you have one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: David you took wrong track actually i am not talking about version control like perforce or svn, my question is regarding like if there are 10 parameters ot wd mine version 1.0 or if there are 12 param then it wd may 1.1 etc, like in that sense i am talking. I always want assurance that with these strings i will generate some key and this key will be write into the xml, then in framework i will calculate that key by those param so there is always assurance that data generated by tool is as same version with the current frame work version.

Comment: Some language have mecanisms that let you do that. When serializing in .NET you can define tag before properties that will determine if it's mandatory or not and whats not.